# Optimizing database queries in Django

Tags: django

I have a bit of code that is causing my page to load pretty slow (49 queries in 128 ms). This is the landing page for my site -- so it needs to load snappily.

The following is my views.py that creates a feed of latest updates on the site and is causing the slowest load times from what I can see in the Debug toolbar:

```
def product_feed(request):
    """ Return all site activity from friends, etc. """
    latestparts = Part.objects.all().prefetch_related('uniparts').order_by('-added')
    latestdesigns = Design.objects.all().order_by('-added')
    latest = list(latestparts) + list(latestdesigns)
    latestupdates = sorted (latest, key = lambda x: x.added, reverse = True)
    latestupdates = latestupdates [0:8]
    # only get the unique avatars that we need to put on the page so we're not pinging for images for each update
    uniqueusers = User.objects.filter(id__in = Part.objects.values_list('adder', flat=True))
    return render_to_response("homepage.html", {
    "uniqueusers": uniqueusers,
    "latestupdates": latestupdates
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The query that causes the most time seem to be:

```
  latest = list(latestparts) + list(latestdesigns) (25ms)
```

There is another one that's 17ms (sitewide annoucements) and 25ms (adding tagged items on each product feed item) respectively that I am also investigating.

Does anyone see any ways in which I can optimize the loading of my activity feed?

Answer (score 1):

You never need more than 8 items, so limit your queries. And don't forget to make sure that `added` in both models [is indexed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-index).

```
latestparts = Part.objects.all().prefetch_related('uniparts').order_by('-added')[:8]
latestdesigns = Design.objects.all().order_by('-added')[:8]
```

For bonus marks, eliminate the magic number.

Comment: Sorry, noob here. What do you mean by 'limit your queries'.  What do you mean by 'magic number'?  I'm going to research indexing now and exactly what that does/means.

Comment: Oops figured out what you mean by the first one.

Answer (score 0):

After making those queries a bit faster, you might want to check out [memcache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs) to store the most common query results.

Answer (score 0):

Moreover, I believe `adder` is `ForeignKey` to `User` model.

```
Part.objects.distinct().values_list('adder', flat=True)
```

Above line is `QuerySet` with unique `addre` values. I believe you ment exactly that.

It saves you performing a subuery.